# transpose pandas dataframe with dynamic columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have a Input dataframe:

import pandas as pd

```
# Define the input data
data = {
    'ID':  [500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 400, 400, 400, 400, 300, 200],
    'item': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C',  'E',   'D',    'E'],
    'Quantity': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5]
}
# Convert the input data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I need to transform this input as you can see in below output example:

[image]

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does `df.pivot('ID', 'item', 'Quantity')` not work ?

Comment: as @Psidom said, pivot should work. `df.pivot(index='ID', columns='item', values='Quantity')`

Comment: @Psidom `pivot` is keyword only now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['item'], prefix="", prefix_sep="").groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).sum().drop("Quantity", axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question… this is not at all what is described in the question (and if it was, a `crosstab` would be much better)

Comment: @mozway Well it outputs the desired state, isn't that what matters for an answer? :D. But I should confess that I was not familiar with `pivot` and actually learned something new while looking at what others said.

Comment: It does **not** give the desired output (check again). It fully ignores the Quantity and only counts the number of occurrences of each "item" (like a `crosstab`)

Comment: you are totally right, my bad @mozway. Thanks for your guidance.